# How to add a filter to entityview in Liquid template

Tags: dynamics-crm, liquid, adxstudio-portals

I'm using **entityview** to retrieve records from CRM using a liquid template. This is the code I use.

```
{% entityview logical_name:'new_consul', name:"Most Recent Consul" %}
{% assign cons = entityview.records %}
{% for item in cons %}
```

But I would like to add a filter to limit to 5 the results, so if I use this code:

```
{% assign count = count | default: 5 %}
{% assign recent_cons = entityview.records | recent: count %}
```

I get following error: *Liquid syntax error: Error - Filter 'recent' does not have a default value for 'lang' and no value was supplied*

What makes me think that filter should is applied correctly, so I then tried with:

```
{% assign languagecode = 'English' %}
{% assign recent_cons = entityview.records | recent: count,languagecode %}
```

But then I get this error: *Liquid error: Missing a valid input parameter. Parameter name: input*

How can I apply the filter to this entitiview query correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it on the adxstudios Portal documentation.

> https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/configuration-guide/liquid-templates/tags/crm-entity-tags/#page_size

```
{% entityview logical_name:'new_consul', name:"Most Recent Consult", page_size:5 %}
```